# magento 1.9 - move block into a product page

Tags: php, xml, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I want move block that contain "wrapper.phtml" under short description in product page.

I have to work with view.phtml or with catalog.xml?

How Can I move this block?

Comment: can you please elaborate it move block what do you mean by this

Answer (score 1):

For moving block into product page,
you have to put code in catalog.xml.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
```

For Example:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="{your_file_path}/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the block using catalog.xml. you can find block with name "product.info.options.wrapper" in catalog.xml

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But, for the sake of information, refer to http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/ for an answer in the "Removing, rearranging and replacing template blocks" section. As stated there:

> There are two ways to remove blocks in layout XML:
>
> by using: `<remove name="" />`
>
> by using: `<action method="unsetChild">`

Also: it is **BAD PRACTICE** to change Magento core files as suggested by others. You should work in a local.xml file, or your own module XML. I strongly recommend studying Magento more.